# Add calculated row to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data like the following and I'd like to add rows that calculate the geometric mean of groups of rows.

```
F1 F2 F3 Type Val  
Y  Y  Y  A    1
Y  Y  Y  B    4
Y  Y  Y  C    7
Y  N  Y  A    3
Y  N  Y  B    2
Y  N  Y  C    5
Y  N  N  A    8
Y  N  N  B    9
Y  N  N  C    3
```

I'd like to add three rows to the above data frame

```
Y  Y  Y GeoM 3.04
Y  N  Y GeoM 3.11
Y  N  N GeoM 6.00
```

@Brenbarn and @chthonicdaemon helped me get close to what I want:
    from scipy.stats import gmean
    import pandas as pd

```
data = {'F1': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
 'F2': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
 'F3': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
 'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
 'Val': [1, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gb = df.groupby(['F1','F2','F3'])['Val'].apply(gmean).to_frame()
gb.columns = ['Val']
gb['Type'] = 'GeoM'
gb.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.append(gb, ignore_index=True)



      F1 F2 F3  Type       Val
0   Y  Y  Y     A  1.000000
1   Y  Y  Y     B  4.000000
2   Y  Y  Y     C  7.000000
3   Y  N  Y     A  3.000000
4   Y  N  Y     B  2.000000
5   Y  N  Y     C  5.000000
6   Y  N  N     A  8.000000
7   Y  N  N     B  9.000000
8   Y  N  N     C  3.000000
9   Y  N  N  GeoM  6.000000
10  Y  N  Y  GeoM  3.107233
11  Y  Y  Y  GeoM  3.036589
```

Comment: You can group on multiple columns with `groupby`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use `groupby` to produce the geometric means:

```
from scipy.stats import gmean

data = {'F1': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
        'F2': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
        'F3': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
        'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Val': [1, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 3]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

gmeans = df.groupby(['F1', 'F2', 'F3']).agg(lambda x: gmean(list(x)))
```

However, I think you should refrain from adding these columns to the original dataframe. It seems to make sense if you're used to adding calculated columns to Excel, but it is unlikely that you really want these new values mixed in with your original data.

If you really must add these as rows, you can do it as follows:

```
gmeans['Type'] = 'GeoM'

newdata = pandas.concat([data, gmeans.reset_index()], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @chthonicdaemon that is close to what I want, however if I try to merge the means and the data frame I don't get what I'd expect.

Comment: I've added code to merge the means into the old data, but see my comment above - it is highly unlikely that you really want derived data together with the old data.